# SQL Circular Dependency

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to design a database schema for the following entities: Stores, Products, Discounts and Buyers. The goal is to provide a discount campaign for a couple of products. However, on my first iteration over the database schema I can see there is a circular dependency as illustrated bellow:

[image]

The question is: Is having such dependencies a bad SQL Design ? Also, how can I include the entity of Buyer that will represent reference the product and the discount used ?Thank you.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Stores` and `Discounts`?

Comment: According to your design multiple discounts could be applied to the same product. Is it fine? How one discount is chosen (or calculated)? May be just one column DiscountId (nullable) should be added to the Product table. Also I would make Products-Stores to be many-tomany But actually the design is fine (IMHO).

Comment: @eggyal Stores 1 - M Discounts

Comment: @StanislavL it's fine since some of the products can be part of several discount campaigns.

Comment: Looks ok to me. There doesn't seem to be any circular dependency.

Comment: Can a store have a discount? I think that's where the problem lies in the ERD. A store has products, and a product can have a discount. If this is the case then there is no 'circular dependency'. As the line from store to discounts shouldn't be there.

Comment: think at discounts as discount campaigns, then more products will be in one discount campaign

Comment: Then create other tables, as a 'discount campaign' is not a direct attribute of the store, but rather of the product. Could add 2 more tables, `campaign`, `campaign_product_discount`, then link the `product` and `discount` tables.

Comment: yep, that will solve the problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see such a "circular dependency" in your model. Look at it as an oriented (or directed) graph. It's impossible to start from one entity and return to it going neither clockwise nor counter-clockwise.

Comment: then you find the diagram to be suitable ?

Comment: @alexsc yes, I don't think this model will break your application

Answer (score 1):

I don't have ERD software, but I would do something like this:
[sample store erd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl3tL.png)

Or:

[image]

Comment: This makes sense. The stock table will have all the products that were ever inventoried, along with an indicator to whether or not the product is still available, and the discount of the product at a specific point in time.

Comment: try to imagine discounts as discount campaigns where one product can be subject of several campaigns..I don't think this diagram will support this use case.

Comment: @alexsc I think I understand what you're saying. I think this could be solved by adding another bridging table though.

Answer (score 0):

No circular reference, which are not incorrect by definition: e.g. employee with foreign key to department (employee works at) and a foreign key from department to employee (is managed by).

An design flaw I do see: this model enables a discount from shop A on a product from shop B.

If you want to prevent this, you can add StoreId to the primary (or alternate unique key) of both Products and Discounts, add the column to Product_Discounts and make it part of both foreign keys.

As for incorporating the Buyer: you'll want to create a Buyers, Sales and Sales_Items tables.

- **Buyers** represent buyers who have made zero one or more...
- **Sales**: representing an event where a Buyer bought zero (not likely), one or more ...
- **Sales_Items** representing zero, one or more items of the same product in a Sale

Finally, you'll need a **Sales_Items_Products_Discount** table, to store the product discount applied to a sales item.

Comment: Title casing / pluralizing table names makes baby Jesus cry.

Comment: There's many different preferences on naming styles, and this is not yours, I assume. Well, actually, it is not mine as well, but I tried to maintain the same style as used in the question, because I think that mixing styles is the worst style.

Comment: Or, set forth some standards and heal the structure over time. The pool may be dirty, but if you don't start cleaning it, it will always be dirty.